# SignalR How to stop controller action method code from executing when Disconnected() is called

Tags: .net, signalr, signalr-hub

I have an application which allows user to upload an excel file which contains thousands of data, then in the controller action method code it take few minutes to process each row and import into the system.

I use signalR because I want to display back the percentage of process in real time to the user.

However, I also want the ability to stop code from executing if user presses the STOP button.

Javascript: I call this from the client

```
$.connection.hub.stop() // this javascript is called from client
```

C#: this method will be called in server code

```
// then this action will be called 
public override Task OnDisconnected(bool stopCalled)
{
    // what should i put here??
    return base.OnDisconnected(stopCalled);
}
```

This will stop connection however it does not stop the controller action code from continuing to execute for the next 5-10 minutes or so and it is waste of resources.

The below code does not work since when Hub is Disconnected Response.IsClientConnected is still true and the loop continues to run.

```
// controller action method code:
for (int i = 0; i < rows.Count; i++)
{
    if (!Response.IsClientConnected) // this is true even when disconnected, however this code will work if the user completely exits the browser tab.
    {
        Response.End();
    }

    // process this row
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't stop the connection (by calling stop()) on the hub, rather you should create a method which can be called on the client side that stops whatever the server is doing.. (CLIENT->SERVER)

Comment: @DOMZE thanks for your comment but any justification as to why i shouldn't use $.connection.hub.stop()? it seems to do what I wanted which is stop the connection. Now all I need is a way for the server to check that the connection to the client is still alive or not, if not alive then stop the code from executing more.

Comment: Assuming you start using SignalR for other things, this will stop all connections to it.

So assuming you have a notification system that listens, this will be stopped too

Comment: @DOMZE ok thanks for your comment ill look more into signalR

Answer (score 1):

You can create public methods on your hub class and then access those methods by calling them from scripts in a web page.

Assuming you want to do that, you can create a method in your Hub class called StopProcess()

```
public void StopProcess()
{
    Clients.Caller.onStopProcess();
}
```

Clients in the browser can then call that method to stop the process:

```
$.connection.hub.stopProcess();
```

Then in your javascript you can have:

```
$.connection.hub.onStopProcess = function() { 
    //what you want your client to do
};
```